# loading multiple data using ajax from single page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the below code to get http response from php page which works fine, However I was wondering if I could have another query on that php page and show the that data on the main page. Should I have a single page for every request I make?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});

var loadData = function() {
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "second.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $(".display").html(response);
            setTimeout(loadData, 1000); 
        }

    });
};
```

second.php

```
 //first query
$inbox = $msg->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages where to_user = ?  and deleted != ? and del2 != ? and is_read = '' order by id desc");
 echo $msg->error;
 $inbox->bind_param('sss', $username->username, $username->username, $username->username );
 $inbox->execute();
 $unread = $inbox->get_result();

   //second query
  $stmt2 = $msg->prepare("");
  $stmt2->bind_param('', $var....
```

html

```
 <div class="display"></div><!--The response is displayed here-->

  <div></div><!--I want the the result of second query to be displayed here-->
```

Comment: If you want to display the results of this two requests in the same place (in your case : `$(".display").html(response);` ) at the same time, you can output them in one response. Less ajax requests. Same result.

Comment: @Tseho not in the same place.

Comment: So, it's two differents responses. You will need to have two ajax requests.

You can use two differents php files but you could also try something like this : 
`url: "second.php?data=users",` and `url: "second.php?data=messages",`

with :
`if (isset($_GET["data"]) && $_GET["data"] === "users") { //first request }
if (isset($_GET["data"]) && $_GET["data"] === "messages") { //second request }`